# Flutter : A problem occurred while calling the api from initstate

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to call the api before the screen is drawn.
Below is the code I wrote.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _eventList= StreamController<Map>.broadcast();
    fetchItems();
    super.initState();
  }

  fetchItems() async {
    print('start fetchItems');
    await flumesState.getFlumeList();
    print('end fetchItems');
  }
```

I'm expecting the widget to be drawn after the `fetchItems` function has finished executing. However, after the `fetchItems` function is executed and the widget is drawn, the execution of the function is finished. What's the problem?

[image]

The direction I want is **start fetchItems** -> **[Instance of ~..]** -> **end fetchItems** -> **build widget**

Comment: you might want o use this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Have you considered to use a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)?

Comment: @Peter Koltai I don't like the time it takes in the beginning, so I'm avoiding it

Comment: There's nothing you can do about the fact that `build` can and will be called at any time - and that includes before you've fetched the items from the API. What you need to do is to allow for that. Until such time that the items are available, you still need to show something to your user - maybe a progress indicator. In `build`, you need to allow for the possibility (actually certainty!) that it will be called before the items are available. If no items are available, have `build` return a placeholder. `FutureBuilder` (see comment above) helps to do this and reduces a bit of boilerplate.